# AS3 override public function both are called?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I am a little confused by this concept.

If I override a public function in a base class, I would have thought that this override function is called and the original is ignored? though this doesn't seem to be the case...

```
public class AbstractScreen extends Sprite
{

    public function AbstractScreen() 
    {

    }


    public function updateLanguage():void
    {
        trace("WARNING: need to override public function updateLanguage()");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Start extends AbstractScreen
{
    override public function updateLanguage():void
    {
        title.text = _model.language.start
        title.setTextFormat(titleFormat);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ViewManager extends Sprite
{
    private var _model:Model;
    private var _screens:Array;


    public function ViewManager(model:Model) 
    {
        _model = model;

        _model.addEventListener(AppEvent.INIT_VIEW, initViews);
        _model.addEventListener(AppEvent.UPDATE_VIEW, updateView);
        _model.addEventListener(AppEvent.CHANGED_LANGUAGE, changeLanguage);
    }

    private function initViews(e:AppEvent):void
    {
        trace("View Manager: initViews");
        _screens = new Array(new Start(_model), new TakePhoto(_model));
        dispatchEvent(new ViewEvent(ViewEvent.VIEW_READY));
    }

    private function changeLanguage(e:AppEvent):void
    {
        for each (var screen:AbstractScreen in _screens)
        {
            screen.updateLanguage();
        }
    }
}
```

If my model dispatches a CHANGED_LANGUAGE event, the text in the views gets updated, But I also get a trace of "WARNING: need to override public function updateLanguage()" What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide us with more contextual information, because the code you have written here should be working correctly. I have tested this code and it worked as expected.

Comment: are you sure you aren't calling this method somewhere in the baseClass too?

Comment: Please see edited question for better context. All my base class does is define a few functions that should be implemented.

Comment: @davivid If your functions never have code in the body in your base class you should use `Interfaces` instead an abstract base class.

Comment: @DanielB a few of the functions eventually will, some shared listeners and UI assets. I did initially use Interfaces, but then realised a lot of functionality would be shared between screens

Comment: Then you could use booth, define the functions that have functionality within a base class and the "optional" functions which have to exist in an interface. If the interface isn't implemented, you know, there is no function and the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this should not call the base class function. Are you sure there is no call to

```
super.initLanguage()
```

within your override?

Most IDE's add this call in the function body automatically, if they create an override for you.

## EDIT

From your edit I see your are iterating over two objects of the types `Start` and `TakePhoto`. I assume `TakePhoto` is also derived from `AbstractScreen` and the trace may be comming from this one.

Also I suggest to use the abstract base class in your iteration.

```
for each (var screen:AbstractScreen in _screens)
{
    screen.updateLanguage();
}
```

Comment: Yes and the more screens I add (PickPhoto, PickCard, etc) the more of that trace I get. Changing to abstract base class the iteration, doesnt solve it. Thanks for your help this really is confusing me!

Comment: No, it's not solving the problem until you override the function in your other derived classes (PickPhoto, PickCard, etc).

Comment: Extend your trace to `trace("WARNING: need to override public function updateLanguage()", this);` and you will see from which derived class the trace comes.

Comment: OMG I feel like an idiot! Adding `this` to the trace, I found a couple of classes I didn't think/know I was working with at the moment. Cheers!